# How to correct the azimuth obtained from coordinates of two points.

Tags: trigonometry, python

Assuming we have points $A (-0.4664, 0.7104)$ and $B (-1.8112, 2.8032)$.
To calculate their azimuth the following equation may be used: $$\text{Azimuth}=\tan^{-1}\frac{X_B-X_A}{Y_B-Y_A}=\tan^{-1}\frac{-1.3448}{2.0928}=-32.72415526582776^\circ$$
However, based on the sign of $X_B-X_A<0$ and $Y_B-Y_A>0$ this angle must be found in quadrant 4 and thus should range between $270$ and $360$ degrees. (The azimuth is measured clockwise from the north or positive y-axis). To correct this angle, we can add/subtract $180$ or $360$ to the calculated azimuth. In this case, adding 360 will solve the issue since $360-32.73272415526582776=327.2672$ degrees.

My question is the following: If for the same example, the calculated azimuth was found to be $32$ degrees. How do we correct this sort of angle? Since adding/subtracting $180$ and $360$, in this case, will not help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  Start by putting `$` signs around all math expressions (including numbers).

Answer (score 2):

All mathematical libraries define an azimuth $A$ which is 0 along $+x$
and increasing counter-clock-wise such that it is 90 deg at $+y$.
If you're defining your own azimuth convention with $A'=0$ along $+y$
and $A'=90$ deg along $+x$, the relation between the two azimuths
is A'= -A+90 deg. So you need to invert the angle obtained
with the usual programming languages and add 90 or subtract 270 degrees afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you look for the function arctan2(y,x):

```
from numpy import arctan2
azimuth = - arctan2(-1, 0) + math.pi/2
if azimuth < 0:
    azimuth = azimuth + 2 * math.pi
```

will give you $\pi$ (x=0, y=-1) and it returns the correct angles from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For this specific case, using the arctan2 is not valid since to measure azimuth we move clockwise from positive y. Thus, the fourth quadrant is to the left of the first quadrant rather than below it (when compared to the typical trigonometric functions). By using arctan2 the angle obtained is $ 120 degrees. However, it still does not belong to the range needed  [ 270, 360] degrees.

Comment: What about the new version?

Comment: Using the new method, the angle obtained is $ 121 degrees.

Comment: when I enter your values: azimuth = - arctan2(2.0928, -1.3448) + math.pi/2 then I get 327.2758447341722 deg. You need to put arctan2(y,x) not arctan2(x,y) !

Comment: Yes!!! My bad its been a long day.. Thank you! Can this function be used for any angle in any quadrant?

Comment: Yes. I have tested it for all four quadrants